# Use ACTION_VIEW with Google Plus android

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

I need to create buttons for social sharing in my Android app.
I've used ACTION_VIEW to open url with specific text in browser for sharing. Here some examples:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+trackable));
                startActivity(browserIntent);

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+trackable));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
```

How can I do the same interacting with google+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ShareCompat.IntentBuilder from the support library. For instance:

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
         .setText("Hello Google+!")
         .getIntent()
         .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
```

A more elegant and expandable solution (specific to Google+) is to use Google Play Services' [PlusShare.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusShare.Builder.html) (here also supplying a link):

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
          .setType("text/plain")
          .setText("Hello Google+!")
          .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
          .getIntent();
```

Note that this doesn't open the browser; it will open the Google+ app to allow the user to share comfortably from the app.